# The core of Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I heard that the core product of Java EE is EJB 3.x? Is that true ?

Comment: Note: it hasn't been "J2EE" for some time now. The official name is "Java Enterprise Edition" or "Java EE"

Answer (score 5):

The Java EE specification was intended to specify how vendors would support transactional, distributed components that were called Enterprise Java Beans.  The "Enterprise" distinguished them from POJOs, because they were intended to run in a separate application server that would handle all the issues around life cycle, threading, and services.

There are a lot of pieces in the Java EE toolkit: servlets, JSPs, Enterprise Java Beans, services such as messaging, naming, pooling, etc., relational database access, connectors to resources such as mainframes, and more.

Picking something as "core" would be like picking a "favorite" child.  Better to consider them as a whole.

UPDATE: If you don't use entity EJBs, you don't need persistence or JDBC.  You can write stateless session beans and be perfectly happy.

If you don't use an HTTP client, you don't need servlets or JSPs.

You don't use what you don't need.

Comment: don't you need other j2ee technologies to implement EJB's ? like jndi , jdbc etc. These are j2ee components and Is EJB a full fledge component ?

Comment: I would call them "JavaEE technologies" rather than components, since "component" already has a well-defined meaning in JavaEE.  But yes, the EJB spec builds on other technologies.

Comment: No, I specifically chose the word "components" because that's what the specification is about.  It refers to your EJBs, not the services/technologies built into the app server.

Comment: Sorry, for the ambiguity... I agree with your use of "components".  I was responding to user581734, who appeared to be saying that jndi/jdbc were "j2ee components".

Answer (score 2):

The core product of J2EE is their containers.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, when I look at the [Java EE 6 specifications page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html), I see dozens of technologies. EJB 3.x is one of them, but there are many others:

[image: JavaEE 6 technologies]

Comment: yeah but isn't EJB the single most biggest technology on the list? Because to implement EJB's you need a lot of other small small technologies ?

Comment: @user EJB 3 is what ties it all together, but you can use most of these without EJB 3 also.

Comment: what technology comes at #2 ?